# Move value from row below to adjacent column in SQL

Tags: sql, database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I would need some help with below case:
My data contains dates of order arrival in one column.
[image]

I want to add second column what would use date from one row below:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `lead()`:

```
select t.dept, t.date as arrival, t.next_arrival
from (select t.*, lead(date) over (partition by dept order by date) as next_arrival
      from t
     ) t
where t.next_arrival is not null;
```

If you are happy with all rows in the result set and the `next_arrival` being `NULL`, then you don't need the subquery.

Comment: I added a rule for NULL: `IFNULL(lead(date) over (partition by dept order by date), '9999-12-31') as next_arrival`

Comment: @marcin2x4 . . . That has nothing to do with your question, which does not include such a default value.  But it is a perfectly legitimate thing to do -- except I would recommend the three-argument form of `LEAD()` instead.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to post this addition to my question. `lead(date,1,'999-12-31')` is indeed better ;)